# Joining two .csv files in Ruby by id when their respective row numbers do not match

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv, join

Say I have a .csv file like this, call it A.csv

```
1234   a   d   g   j   m   p   s
5678   b   e   h   k   n   q   t
9012   c   f   i   l   o   r   u
```

and another, call it B.csv, like

```
1234   g   a   q   o
NULL   0   0   0   0
NULL   0   0   0   0
9012   l   h   k   p
```

I only want to join where the first columns' id's match regardless of whether they're in the same row number or not. It's important to note that `B.csv`'s id's ⊆ `A.csv`'s id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution, that I came with:

```
require 'csv'

h = {}
CSV.foreach("path/to/A.csv") do |row|
  h[row.shift] = row
end

CSV.foreach("path/to/B.csv") do |row|
  next unless h.key?(row[0])
  h[row.shift] << row
end

h.each do |k,_| 
  h[k].flatten!
end

h
=>{1234=>["a", "d", "g", "j", "m", "p", "s", "g", "a", "q", "o"], 5678=>["b", "e", "h", "k", "n", "q", "t"], 9012=>["c", "f", "i", "l", "o", "r", "u", "l", "h", "k", "p"]}
```